# JavaFX TableView displays null values

Tags: java, javafx, filter, null

I've recently encountered interesting problem. I have a table with 1 int and 3 String columns. I have implemented filtering for the table that works perfectly fine except one minor point: Whenever there is at least one filtered result (but less than the amount of visible rows), the int column display nulls as the values for empty rows. If the amount of found matches is, however more than visible number of rows, no null values are added (even with scroll functionality). This is best described with the pictures:

[image: with null values]

Filter for non-existent value does not display nulls:

[image: without null values]

The code for filtering:

```
    FilteredList<Word> filteredData = new FilteredList<>(masterData,e->true);
    SortedList<Word> sortedData = new SortedList<>(filteredData);
    sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(table.comparatorProperty());
    table.setItems(sortedData);
    TextField filter = new TextField();
    filter.setPromptText("Filter");
    filter.textProperty().addListener((observableValue,oldValue,newValue)->{
        filteredData.setPredicate((Predicate<? super Word>) word->{
            if(word.getAllCz().toLowerCase().contains(newValue.toLowerCase()))return true;
            else if(word.getAllEng().toLowerCase().contains(newValue.toLowerCase()))return true;
            else if(String.valueOf(word.getUnitNo()).equals(newValue))return true;
            else return false;
        });
    });
```

CellValue factory:

```
    column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>(data));
    column.setCellFactory(tc-> {
        TableCell<Word, Integer> cell = new TableCell<>();
        Text text = new Text();
        cell.setGraphic(text);
        text.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
        text.setStyle("-fx-fill: -fx-text-background-color;");
        text.setFontSmoothingType(FontSmoothingType.LCD);
        text.wrappingWidthProperty().bind(column.widthProperty().subtract(5));
        text.textProperty().bind(cell.itemProperty().asString());
        return cell;  
    });
```

Comment: Please include the code which sets the first column’s cellValueFactory.

Comment: Do you have a custom cell factory on that column? If so, post it. Aside: do you realize you are continually adding more and more listeners to the text field's text property? Eventually this will bring the application to a standstill. There's also no need to create a new sorted list every time the text changes.

Comment: I've added a cellValueFactory. James_D thank you for pointing that out.. I'm still new to this so I haven't noticed.

Comment: @kleopatra I don't really understand what you mean. Could you please explain in more detail?

Comment: Hmh I think I've already done that as a result of james_d answer.. I've edited the question to reflect the code I have now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the cell is empty, its item will be `null`, and `itemProperty().asString()` will evaluate to a string containing the literal word "null" (similar to passing a null value to a `PrintStream`). Your binding needs to treat empty cells as special cases:

```
column.setCellFactory(tc-> {
    TableCell<Word, Integer> cell = new TableCell<>();
    Text text = new Text();
    cell.setGraphic(text);
    text.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
    text.setStyle("-fx-fill: -fx-text-background-color;");
    text.setFontSmoothingType(FontSmoothingType.LCD);
    text.wrappingWidthProperty().bind(column.widthProperty().subtract(5));
    text.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
        if (cell.isEmpty()) {
            return null ;
        } else {
            return cell.getItem().toString();
        }
    }, cell.emptyProperty(), cell.itemProperty()));
    return cell;  
});
```

or you need to override `updateItem()`:

```
column.setCellFactory(tc-> {
    TableCell<Word, Integer> cell = new TableCell<>() {
        private Text text = new Text();
        {
            this.setGraphic(text);
            text.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
            text.setStyle("-fx-fill: -fx-text-background-color;");
            text.setFontSmoothingType(FontSmoothingType.LCD);
            text.wrappingWidthProperty().bind(column.widthProperty().subtract(5));
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Integer item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (empty) {
                text.setText(null);
            } else {
                text.setText(item.toString());
            }
        }
    };
    return cell;  
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've used the second approach as the first gave me an error at `createStringBinding(()` . Could I ask one more thing: If an empty cell with an integer item evaluated to "null" String, why didn't my empty String cells do the same?

Comment: Fixed the error in the binding version. I can't really comment on behavior of code I can't see; did you use `asString()` in the bindings for the cell for the string columns too (that would be strange, since they are already strings).

Comment: The code for Strings is almost identical except that when binding I have `text.textProperty().bind(cell.itemProperty());`

Comment: @zotmer So that explains it, no?

Comment: Oh yes I finally get it now. The method `asString()` converts the null value into a String "null". Since we don't use the `asString()` in the rest of the columns, the null value is passed in correctly and nothing is displayed. Thanks once again for your help.